# dtype Error while running sample Cupy on python

Tags: pandas, cupy, python-3.11

I am running the following test code:

```
import cupy as cp
import pandas as pd
arr = [{'df1': pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}),
'df2': pd.DataFrame({'C': [7, 8, 9], 'D': [10, 11, 12]})},
{'df1': pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7]}),
'df2': pd.DataFrame({'C': [8, 9, 10], 'D': [11, 12, 13]})}]

def my_calculation(d):
    df1 = d['df1']
    df2 = d['df2']
    return df1.groupby('A').mean() + df2.groupby('C').mean()

my_vec_calculation = cp.vectorize(my_calculation)

result = my_vec_calculation(arr)

print(result)
```

I get the following error:

```
    return arg.dtype.char
           ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my code above.

I am unable to use `cudf`. Is there a way to modify the above code to use it  without using `cudf`

Comment: what is your desired output from the code above?

Answer (score -1):

There is a bit wrong with this code,

1. from the initialization of an array of dataframes.  Not sure what
   you're doing that, unless you're trying to iterate between the
   dataframes programmatically, and even so...let me not venture to guess; can you pleas clarify what you're really trying to do and why?
2. assuming you HAVE to do it this way, as it is written, you have to then drop down another level in the array and call each dataframe in your `my_calculation` function similar to `d[0]["df1"]` instead of d['df1'].
3. You instantiate `my_vec_calculation` as an equation when you try to use
   it as a function that passes a variable. Just create a new function
   that passes the array variable.  What you have right now is really boils down to you wanting the output of `result = cp.vectorize(my_calculation(arr))`.
4. I'm really not sure what you wish to do with your outputs of your groupby means. but right now, you have NAs being returns in my best case (that's after i get actual values doing `df1.groupby('A').mean()` You can't add them together like this, even if you figure out exactly what you're trying to do with the 0 and 1 elements of your array and how you plan to use them.  Can you make some clarifying comments and i'll update the answer?

Other pointers: cuPY is a GPU library with a similar API to numpy in the same way that cuDF is a GPU library with a similar API to pandas.  Try making it easy on yourself by using numpy instead to keep it all on the CPU as you experiment in understanding the library API and hte outputs, and then quickly  graduate to a GPU workflow when you can get cuDF working for the transfer to all GPU only with cudf and cupy (unless

Comment: You are debating why I set my sample code the way I did. The reason the sample code looks the way it does it cause of my real life computation is like that. Unless you are a nuclear physicist there is no point in getting into why that is so :)

Comment: happy to move some of this to comments, but the question from OP was: "I am not sure what is wrong with my code above.".  This answers some of "what is wrong" and asks for clarification, because I did try and get it into working condition, saw what he did wrong, and hit hurdles.  If OP wants, he can rephrase the ask. and provide a desired end result.

Comment: @Zanam, right now, you are returning a data frame of NAs made of columns B&D in `my_calculation`.  If you read fully, I asked about why you set it up this way, but i was far more interested in what your example's desired outputs look like because of that error.  I also don't think the issue is that this requires a nuclear physicist (one day, i can ask the one in my fam) since your current issue in my version of the code is in how you intend to join df1's and df2's groupby mean in `my_calculation` to vectorize, but I'm not a nuclear physicist, so what do I know?  Sorry I couldn't help you more.